# Finding string in the beginning of a larger string

Tags: c#

I'm trying to find, in an array of strings, which one **starts** with a particular substring.  One of the strings in the array is guaranteed to start with the particular substring.

I tried to use:

```
int index = Array.BinarySearch (lines, "^"+subString);
```

Where lines is the array of strings and I'm looking for the index of the array that **starts** with subString.  However, I'm either using regex improperly or there's a much better way to go about this?

Comment: _using regex improperly_ There is no RegEx involved in BinarySearch, just IComparable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BinarySearch` can be used only to find a complete string, so you cannot use it for a substring match. You also have to ensure that the array is ordered in the first place to use `BinarySearch`.

You can use `Array.FindIndex`:

```
int index = Array.FindIndex(lines, line => line.TrimStart().StartsWith(subString));
```

Comment: Other comments probably would have worked, but still using Array was the closest thing to my current code.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to find the **index** of the (first) occurence, or do you need to find the **actual strings** that match that criterium?

```
myString.StartsWith(myPrefix); //returns bool
```

That should do the trick. Or a little more verbose:

```
var matchedLines = lines.Where(line => line.StartsWith(substring)).ToList();
```

If you need the index of the first occurence, I'd address it as an array:

```
var firstOccurence = String.Empty;
var firstOccurenceIndex = -1;

for(int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    if(lines[i].StartsWith(substring))
    {
        firstOccurence = lines[i];
        firstOccurenceIndex = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

*Note: you don't HAVE to use an array. It could just as well have been done with a foreach, manual counter incrementor and a break statement. I just prefer to work with arrays if I'm looking for an index.*

Answer (score 0):

Yet, another solution:

```
int index = lines.ToList().FindIndex(line => line.TrimStart().StartsWith(subString));
```